# Prevent Dacpac dropping columns via ALTER_TABLE trigger in TSQL

Tags: trigger, ssdt

We're using SSDT to deploy database updates to clients, but sadly they will soon have the ability to add their own columns to tables in their databases. Obviously these won't be included in our model, and as such when we run the dacpac on their database, it will shamelessly drop the columns and any data in them. This is highly undesirable.

I have had some success using a DeploymentContributor to prevent the changes, but it's hard to fit this in with our update process, as such I was hoping to find an SQL only solution.
A database ALTER_TABLE trigger appears to have the power to do what I want, but I'm struggling to find a way to make it prevent the action without throwing an error, which would disrupt the dacpac.

Is there a way for the trigger to block the alter without breaking the dacpac?